# cannot implicitly convert type customB customC

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            C c = new C();
            c = new B();

        }
    }

    class B
    {

    }
    class C : B
    {

    }

}
```

please can anyone explain this error  ? i am new to coding.  i want to check the properties of hiding and overriding the methods. your efforts are highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `B` to a `C`, which is not correct is every case. Try to rename the objects to make it easier:

```
class Animal
{
}

class Dog : Animal
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog ();
        dog = new Animal(); // Oops ! Not possible
    }
}
```

A `Dog` is always an `Animal`, but every `Animal` is not necessarily a `Dog`.

The following would be correct though:

```
Animal animal = new Dog(); // Possible
animal = new Animal(); // Possible too
```

Although in this case, `Animal` probably deserves to be `abstract` (so you wouldn't be able to create one in the first place - you'd have to create a concrete class).

Comment: "Although in this case, `Animal` probably deserves to be `abstract`." Can you call `new` on an `abstract` class?

Comment: @FunctionR You can't. I should have mentioned that. I said this because with the classes named like that, it doesn't make sense to create an animal without specifying the species.

Comment: Exactly! I knew that BTW :) +1 for improving your answer further.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C is of type B, but B is not of type C.

It would work if you wrote it like this:

```
 B b = new C();
 b = new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to coding I don't want to throw technical things at you.  so i'll explain it this way.

you can always convert in 2 cases.
1. the object you are converting from, and to, have a predefined converter created and called
2. the object you are trying to convert from is made up of the smaller object you are trying to convert to.

such as

in life we can assume

```
 Orange : Fruit
```

so we can say

```
eat((Fruit)orange)
```

because orange is made up of a lower class Fruit.

however to convert a *Fruit* to Orange you cannot do because Orange is more complex than just Fruit, and also who is to say this *Fruit* wasn't a Banana, 2 very different things, although still *Fruit*

*As Commented "All oranges are fruit, but not all fruit are oranges"*

Comment: Might want to rephrase that to "All oranges are fruit, but not all fruit are oranges"